# How to get surf2Dwrite to correctly compile in C++ CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-2019

Ignore this question - the code is fine - the problem was with use of C++ header files which are not included in the example shared.

I am using Visual studio 2019 with CUDA 11.0 and I have hit a brick wall trying to use a cudaSurfaceObject_t to store the results of a calculation.

I recieve the following compiler errors

Error   C3861   'surf2Dwrite': identifier not found
Error   C2059   syntax error: '<'

I have stuffed the `include#` section of the .cu file with headers in a vain attempt to get surf2Dwrite to be identified...

My example version of the code is a simple attempt to fill the surface with a `float` of value `NAN`:-

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <cuda.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h> 
    #include "cuda_runtime.h"
    #include "device_launch_parameters.h"
    #include "export.h"
    #include"surface_functions.h" 

    __global__
    void TestGrids(cudaSurfaceObject_t surf, int size)
    {
        int y = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
        int x = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    
        if (x < size && y < size)
        {
            surf2Dwrite(NAN, surf, x * 4, y);//Error C3861 'surf2Dwrite': identifier not found
        }   
    }        
    
    void TestSurfWrite( int size)
    {   
        cudaDeviceProp prop;
        cudaError_t c_err = cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
        
        //Set grid and block sizes
    
        dim3 dimblock(16, 16, 1);   
        int gridDimX = prop.multiProcessorCount;
        int gridDimY = 16;
        while (gridDimX > 2 * gridDimY)
        {
            gridDimX = gridDimX / 2;
            gridDimY = gridDimY * 2;
        }   
        dim3 dimGrid(gridDimX, gridDimY, 1);    
    
        cudaChannelFormatDesc nanchannelDescSurf = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
        cudaArray_t nanArray;
        cudaMallocArray(&nanArray, &nanchannelDescSurf, size, size, 0);
        struct cudaResourceDesc nanDescSurf;
        memset(&nanDescSurf, 0, sizeof(cudaResourceDesc));
        nanDescSurf.resType = cudaResourceTypeArray;
        nanDescSurf.res.array.array = nanArray;
        cudaSurfaceObject_t nanSurf;
        cudaCreateSurfaceObject(&nanSurf, &nanDescSurf);
        
        TestGrids<<<dimGrid, dimblock>>>(nanSurf, size); // Error C2059 syntax error: '<'
        
        c_err = cudaGetLastError();
    
        // perform work on nansurf here..
    
        cudaDestroySurfaceObject(nanSurf);
        cudaFreeArray(nanArray);
    }
```

The above code fails to build with the errors as shown.  The relevant line from the output is as follows:-

```
>Compiling CUDA source file hough.cu...
1>  
1>C:\dev\Test>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_WINDLL -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o x64\Debug\hough.cu.obj "C:\dev\Test\test.cu"  
1>test.cu
```

I'm a beginner with both C++ and CUDA in C++ so I expect there will be an obvious issue here.

talonmies has identified that this is a project set up problem in the comments below - this is an are I have no expertise in and do not really know where to start looking for a solution, so I have added the VisualStudio-2019 tag in the hopes that it will attract someone who does know about these things...

Comment: Something is wrong with your project setup. That code compiles fine

Comment: Thanks for testing the compilation. I'll examine the project setup and see if I can work anything else out..

Comment: @talonmies I've decided to create a new project and port the code over.  I am calling the C++ and CUDA code from a c# program, so I have been creating a standard CUDA Runtime 11.0 project and changing the configuration type to Dynamic library in properties, then inserting CUDA C/C++ files from the Add new items dialog. - Is this the best approach or is this what might be causing the problems.  Is there a better way? Thanks Graham

Comment: @talonmies - For the record that didn't work - I am still getting the same errors.  What #include statements do I need for the surf2Dwrite?  Could this problem be caused by mixing .cpp and .cu code in the project?  if so  can I declare the CUDA code functions__declspec(dllexport) so I can split the cu and cpp code into 2 projects.  I'm very confused!

Comment: You don't need any special includes. I don't use Visual Studio and I can't tell you what to do to fix it. In short: this isn't a code problem, it is a build system problem

Comment: I added simpleSurfaceWrite.cu from the CUDA 11.0 samples to my project and once I have sorted out the #includes - that builds OK.  I have then moved the kernel code above into the simpleSurfaceWrite.cu file and that now builds as well.  I copied all of the #include comments from simpleSurfaceWriter.cu into my test.cu file - and it still refuses to build....
This implies (to me at least) that there is something wrong between the 2 .cu files. Any thoughts anybody?  I guess I now have a work around of sorts as I can strip out the code from the smaple .cu file and replace it with my own code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem arises because I had mangled my header files. I haven't fixed everything yet, but in the process of moving my code into the simpleSurfaceWrite.cu file (as mentioned in the comments) I had to add a header file - at this point I started getting the listed errors again - this time occuring in the simpleSurfaceWrite.cu.

In essence the example code I shared was too over simplified to actually recreate my problem.

Thanks to everyone who had a think about this.
Now I have to tidy up my header files...

UPDATE:
Header files sorted out - code now building and running